# Preparing data for making an ErrorListPlot

Tags: list-manipulation

I often have the following notebook in *Mathematica*, which I use to make a dataset and associated errors:

```
x = {0, 2, 4, 6, 10, 20};
y = {979, 146, 141, 157, 187, 274};
uncY = Sqrt[y];
dataVector = Thread[{x, y}];
```

I want to make an [`ErrorListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html), so I need to add `ErrorBar` with each `uncY`-value as an element in each data pair. So the final `dataVector` should have the form

```
{{x_i, y_i}, Errorbar[uncY_i]}
```

What is an easy way to achieve this, without using a `For`-loop?

Comment: @andre why is that? is it too specific?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your errors input has the form :

```
errorList = {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}
```

Then do :

```
Thread[{dataVector, Errorbar /@ errorList}]  

(* {  
 {{0, 979}, Errorbar[1]},
 {{2, 146}, Errorbar[2]},
 {{4, 141}, Errorbar[1]},
 {{6, 157}, Errorbar[3]},
 {{10, 187}, Errorbar[1]},
 {{20, 274}, Errorbar[2]}
 } *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do all the manipulation in one line if you wish:

```
ErrorListPlot@MapThread[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#2-uncY@#2 ]} &, {x, y}]
```

Comment: I would thumb-up if I had sufficient reputation

Comment: I'll take a virtual thumbs up, cheers ;)

Answer (score 4):

I accidentally discovered that you can use convenient notation `PlusMinus`(`±`) for horizontal and vertical axes

```
ypm = Thread[y ± uncY]
```

[image]

```
ErrorListPlot[Thread[{x, ypm}]]
```

[image]

In your case you can use even more simple method as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23195/4678):

```
ErrorListPlot[Thread[{x, y, uncY}]]
```

Unfortunately, these nice options are still undocumented.