# What's the simplest way to plot an ErrorListPlot with only y error bars?

Tags: plotting, documentation, undocumented

Sometimes I get really tired of [Preparing data for making an ErrorListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21932/745) using `Thread` and friends. Is there a simpler way to plot an ErrorListPlot with only y error bars?

Nothing is mentioned in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html).

Comment: Perhaps I should change this into a self answered Q/A? What's the simplest way to plot an ErrorListPlot?:)

Comment: I agree with the Q/A idea.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed it seems there is a simpler way:

Instead of

```
ErrorListPlot[{{{x1, y1}, ErrorBar[err1]}, {{x2, y2}, ErrorBar[err2]}, ...}]
```

Just do

```
ErrorListPlot[{{x1, y1, dy1}, {x2, y2, dy2} ...}, ...}]
```

Here is an example:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[{{1, 2, 0.5}, {3, 4, 0.1}, {5, 6, 0}}, 
               PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Example error plot]

Why this is not documented is beyond me.

Comment: If you type `??ErrorListPlot`you get the transformation being used: {{ErrorBarPlots`Private`x_?NumericQ, 
   ErrorBarPlots`Private`y_?NumericQ, 
   ErrorBarPlots`Private`e_?
    NumericQ} :> (ErrorBarPlots`Private`error[
      N[{ErrorBarPlots`Private`x, ErrorBarPlots`Private`y}]] = 
     ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-ErrorBarPlots`Private`e, 
       ErrorBarPlots`Private`e}];`